# error in eclipse startapp ads

Tags: java, android

Eclipse tell me that "Multiple markers at this line
    - The method init(Context, String, String, boolean) in 
     the type StartAppSDK is not applicable for the arguments 
     (FlashlightActivity, int, int, boolean)
    - Line breakpoint:FlashlightActivity [line: 61] - 
     ‪onCreate(Bundle)‬"
The problem is the **init**.
In this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StartAppSDK.init(this, 107866170, 208658775, true);
            setContentView(R.layout.flashlight);
    button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);

    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    if (!isCameraSupported(pm)) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("No Camera");
        alertDialog.setMessage("The device's doesn't support camera.");
        alertDialog.setButton(RESULT_OK, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                            final int which) {
                        Log.e("err", "The device's doesn't support camera.");
                    }
```

Comment: That is a basic java error message. Maybe you should start by learning the basics of java before you dig in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

The IDs should be strings, so your init line should be:

```
StartAppSDK.init(this, "107866170", "208658775", true);
```